# Script work, but forever don t start it

Tags: javascript, node.js, forever

I have a script in node.js

It work well when I start it in the classic way

```
$node /path/to/app.js
```

But when I try to use forever with it, it just prompt the version of forever

```
$forever start --plain -m 10 -l log -e err --minUptime 10000 /path/to/app.js
```

It start, but close itself in the middle of the app.

When looking at the log, it seems to happen when I m downloading vital files for starting the app, and I can t know in advance how many time it will take before the download end.

Do I just set --minUptime to something like 1min and hope it to be enought, or is there some way to prevent forever to stop?

Comment: Do you have any message or error in log file? And is your script 10s up? (--uptime: Minimum time a child process has to be up. Forever will `exit` otherwise)

Comment: No, log file aren t even created (err.log is created, but not log)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should be downvoted as hell to not test enougth.

While editing my app I somehow erase a loop counter incrementation, so I had a infinite loop.

It work, but it s slow as hell for some reason (maybe not related to forever, I m working on a Raspberry Pi and even the console is slow)